# Genymotion "The virtual device got no IP address"

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I think I tried every method to get around that error. I turned Hyper V on and off, tried selecting the Allow VMs and Deny options, reinstalling Genymotion without VirtualBox, running them as admin, rebooting, lowering the virtual RAM and CPUs. Nothing worked, here is my setup:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have tried so many solutions, but none of them actually worked until I found a perfect solution. Follow this steps below to solve the minor problem.

1. Open Genymotion, select the emulator You want to run.
2. Click on the spanner icon(Configure Virtual Device) on the selected emulator.
3. A settings window will open, You will see a group box titled "Network mode".
4. Choose the "Bridge" radio button, in the combo box select do not select Intel(R)...(which is selected by default), instead select Hyper-V or Any other option you see in the combo box.(Like me I selected either Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter or Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller).
5. Select any and press the "OK" button, Your emulator should run now.

P.S Make sure You have Intel Virtualization enabled in your BIOS. If it still doesn't work Disable it and Enable it again, it should work just fine.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your network preferences of the virtual machine is configured properly (Allow VMs) and it is still not working, just add the genymotion(also Android Studio) as exceptions on your Windows Firewall. For me it fixed the problem, after I tried some other stuff found on the internet. Btw, I also turned my AV off

Answer (score 0):

Steps 1:

Go to BIOS settings -> Go to System Configuration -> Enable Virtualization Technology -> Save and Exit from BIOS settings.

Steps 2:

Open Oracle VM VirtualBox -> Select your simulator -> Go to settings of simulator -> Select General tab -> Select Basic sub tab -> Select your OS type -> Select your Version of your OS -> Save and Exit

Steps 3:

Restart your Genymotion and Start Genymotion simulator.